# How to reply to (what I consider) personal questions asked by recruiter I just met over LinkedIn?

Tags: professionalism, job-search, recruitment, covid-19, confidentiality

I graduated a couple years ago from university with my degree in tech. I have had a lot of trouble finding a full time, permanent position that uses my degree. Recently I had a recruiter contact me over LinkedIn with a job description that sounded very promising.

The recruiter asked if I was free for a "quick" phone call "to get to know me" and "put a voice to a name". I agreed. The first 3 things she said to me on the phone call were

1. what are my top 3 strengths?
2. how much does my current job pay me?
3. Am I fully vaccinated against COVID?

Even before the phone call there were things that struck me as strange. For example she asked for a copy of my resume in the Word format. I've had recruiters do this so they can rewrite it or apply their template, but this didn't seem to be the case with her, as she just told me some generic changes I should make. Like put work experience above education.

Anyway, I told her on question 3. that I don't like to discuss health information with people I don't know. She asked if we could reschedule the call. I have held short term jobs where a COVID vaccination was required to get into the venue. But I had having someone who contacted me first ask me off so quickly made me feel uncomfortable - though maybe it shouldn't. Is it reasonable to ask putting off the question until at least the first interview with the company they are representing?

To be honest, I'm surprised by the number of people I know that healthcare professional or the governments response to COVID is something to be skeptical about. That's just my opinion. Some of my friend's views rubbed off on me. Presumably she's creating a profile on me that will be put in a database. I could ask who the information is shared with but I would have know way of knowing if it's true.

For #2 I treated the question as "how much do I want to be paid?"

For #1, I told her it would depend on the context such as what type of job. To be honest, to me somethings don't make sense to pick the top 3 (it's like asking what's the smell of the color yellow). Are they usually asking for soft skills or technical skills? What level of granularity? For example are they expecting answers like "Microsoft Windows" or "PowerShell" or "networking with PowerShell"? Also are they looking for more transferable skills (good at organization) or technical skills (good at Java)?

Comment: The 'how much do you get paid' question can be answered just as OP wants, without any dishonesty, by phrasing the reply as "Glad you asked, here's the salary range I'm looking for", and lay down some numbers.

Comment: Any answer to #3 but "yes" or "as much as I can be" is effectively "no". In the US, mandates for employers to have effectively 100% vaccinations are coming, plus individual offices now requiring it. It's only a matter of time https://apnews.com/article/coronavirus-pandemic-joe-biden-business-health-880d2052bb4127fb40bcaaca98514753

Comment: It is nobody business how much I earn. Ever.

Answer (score 15):

These aren't personal questions.

The first, about your strengths, is a bit unusual for a first phone screen. I wouldn't necessarily be sure how to answer in that context, without a specific job. Talking about strengths and weaknesses isn't an uncommon topic in an interview, though. I would expect that a lot of your strengths could be inferred from your resume, based on education and work experience, and there wouldn't be much more. Your answer seems quite reasonable.

Asking about your current compensation is OK in some places, but not in others. You'd need to understand your local laws. The purpose of a question like this is to understand how much you'd need to get paid to change jobs. However, basing this information on current salary tends to perpetuate underpayment, especially for people in jobs that pay below market rate or people who tend to be paid less. Personally, I would interpret this the same way you did, which is as asking what the compensation package would look like for me to accept a new job.

Your question doesn't have a location tag, but in the United States, companies can require employees to be vaccinated against COVID. This seems to be a reasonable question to ensure that if you aren't vaccinated and cannot provide this evidence, you don't waste the time of a company that requires vaccination.

Comment: +1  The first question may just have been to get you talking, to get a feel for how you present yourself as a professional.  The second question is essential for a recruiter to know, there's no point them puttting time and effort into getting you interviews for positions you aren't going to accept because of the remuneration.  Your vaccine status is not private to you since it can affect the health of (and potentially kill) people you'd be working with.

Comment: Your vaccination status is still health information the last time I checked.  You can also still potentially infect someone else regardless of your vaccination status. Being vaccinated just lowers that chance.

Comment: @Donald - regardless, it is a requirement at many companies now. At the one I work at, one would have to indicate it on your application (online).

Comment: I would tell potential employers, but I don't really count a recruiter who I just met as a potential employer. I mean, I'm not one of those people who posted on social media bragging that I got the vaccine.

Comment: @userskoup Think about it from a recruiter's perspective. They get paid by putting candidates in front of companies and getting those candidates hired. A good recruiter will understand what the company needs and put forward the best, most likely to be hired people. It would be a waste of their time to evaluate you, prep you, and put you in front of a company that you won't be hired at because you don't meet a non-negotiable job requirement. If you don't feel comfortable sharing the information that a recruiter needs to do their job, don't work with a recruiter.

Comment: people can feel free to say something Aaron-Rogers like about their vaccination status, but expecting that their personal decisions about it won't affect their employment is childish at best.

Comment: I guess I wasn't thinking clearly. My biggest concern was for someone I didn't know to be recording whether I'm vaccinated or not. I'm getting that it shouldn't be considered private information.